# Inheritance template using Blade

Tags: templates, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have a problem with my inheritance using blade template. So I have my main template: /layouts/main.blade.php

```
@section('oneNews')
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns pad_0">
      <div class="container">
          <div id="da-slider" class="da-slider">
            @foreach($aTopNews as $topNews)
              <div class="da-slide">
                  <h2>{{ $topNews['title'] }}</h2>
                  <p>{{ $topNews['content'] }}.</p>
                  <a href="/news/view/{{ $topNews['id'] }}" class="da-link">Read</a>
                  <div class="da-img">{{ HTML::image($topNews['image']) }}</div>
              </div>
              @endforeach
              <nav class="da-arrows">
                  <span class="da-arrows-prev"></span>
                  <span class="da-arrows-next"></span>
              </nav>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, I want to inherit this template in another template

```
 @extends('layouts.main')

 @section('oneNews')
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns pad_0 marg-top-20">
        Registru on-line
    </div>
  </div>
 @stop
```

Controller :

```
public function getIndex()
{
    return View::make('layouts.main')
        ->with('aNews',     \News::where('type', '=', '0')->get())
        ->with('aTopNews',  \News::where('type', '=', '1')->get())
        ->with('aNotice',   \News::where('type', '=', '2')->get());
}
```

But I get the error : "Undefined variable: aTopNews", Help me please

Comment: Did you define `$aTopNews` when calling the view? please show us your controller code.

Comment: Did you check that you render the correct template?

Comment: Before returning the view in your controller include this line `dd(\News::where('type', '=', '1')->get());` and tell us what it prints out.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, with template inheritance you don't return the layout view, you return the content view and Laravel's Blade engine will take care of fetching and rendering the correct layout: that's the purpose of `@extends` at the begining of the file. So in your controller you should have:

```
return View::make('content'); // assuming content.blade.php contains the code in your example
```

One thing about template inheritance is that it doesn't pass along variables from the child (content) view to the layout view. So doing `View::make('content')->with('aTopNews', $aTopNews)` will only make `aTopNews` available for the `content` view, and not the `layouts.main` view which it extends. To make it available within the layout view you can use `View::share()` which makes the variable available for all views:

```
View::share('aTopNews',  \News::where('type', '=', '1')->get());
```

Also, for section inheritance to work, in your layout file you need to end `@section('oneNews')` with `@show`.

The Laravel Documentation explains very well how [Blade Template Inheritance](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/templates#blade-templating) works.